# Play frame work table not found error in prod mode

Tags: playframework

I am new to Play and am facing a problem while deploying the
application in prod mode.
i am using in memory db to start off....
Play version is 1.2.4
i made  a simple app with entity as

```
@Entity
public class TestModel extends Model {


   public String name;

}
```

and conf as

```
 application.mode=prod
 db=mem
%test.application.mode=prod
%test.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
%test.jpa.ddl=create
 %test.mail.smtp=mock
```

in the controller just for testing what I am doing is

```
     public static void listBars() {

           TestModel bar = new TestModel();

       bar.name = "a new bar";
       bar.save();
       TestModel bar2 = new TestModel();
       bar2.name = "a new bar2";
       bar2.save();



   renderJSON(TestModel.findAll());
}
```

really appreciate if i could get some help on this..The code is working in the dev mode..

The exception trace is

```
       va:116)
       at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(I
entityGenerator.java:90)
       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(Abstr
ctReturningDelegate.java:54)
       ... 24 more
9:57:31,396 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
9:57:31,397 ERROR ~ Table "TESTMODEL" not found; SQL statement:
nsert into TestModel (id, name) values (null, ?) [42102-149]
9:57:31,404 ERROR ~

69772kodd
nternal Server Error (500) for request POST /bars.json

xecution exception (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 30)
ersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: coul
 not insert: [models.TestModel]

lay.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarExcept
on: could not insert: [models.TestModel]
       at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
       at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
aused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGr
mmarException: could not insert: [models.TestModel]
       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityMan
gerImpl.java:1214)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityMan
gerImpl.java:1147)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityMan
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like this to automatically generate your table :

jpa.ddl=create

It's important that you don't regenerate your table every time in prod to prevent lost of data.

See this page: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/production
Section: Disable JPA automatic schema update